# Quick Union Implementation in C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int *id,N;

main()
{
    FILE* file=fopen("a.txt","r");
    int i,p,q,c;
    fscanf(file,"%d",&N);

    id=(int *)malloc(N*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        *(id+i)=i;

    while(!feof(file))
    {
        fscanf(file,"%d %d",&p,&q);
        if(!connected(p,q))
            unn(p,q);
    }
    fclose(file);
    c=1;

    while(c==1)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&p,&q);
        printf("%d\nYes(1) or No(0)    ",connected(p,q));
        scanf("%d",&c);
    }
}

connected(int p,int q)
{
    return((root(p))==(root(q)));
}

unn(int p,int q)
{
    int j=root(q);
    int i=root(p);
    *(id+j)=i;
}

root(int i)
{
    while(i!=(*(id+i)))
        i=*(id+i);
    return(i);
}
```

On compiling, no error message is displayed. However, when I try to execute this program, it says"Segmentation Fault (core dumped). Why does this happen?
As may have noticed, this is an attempt to implement the quick union.

The quick find was implemented without any hassle using the same file "a.txt" with only a few tweaks to this code. 
In running gdb, it says :

"Program recieved signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation Fault
   0x08048729 in rt (i=134761) at i.c:47"

The value of the variable "i", every time I run it, is 134761, which it's not supposed to be since the values only range from 1 to 11 in the text file.
* The Yes or No is for the user's query.

Comment: You should use a debugger to step through the code and where it crashed. Segmentation Fault means a memory access to an invalid address.

Comment: @egur In the rt() function

Comment: NEVER cast the result of malloc()

Comment: you should print out the values of p and q as debugging, to validate they where correctlly readed

Comment: @PeterMiehle How do I do that?

Comment: after scanf() use a fprintf(stderr, "p:%i, q:%i", p, q);

Comment: @PeterMiehle If you mean those in the second while loop, they are for the find queries by the user.

Comment: Please upload an example `a.txt` file.

Comment: @Guido The file I/O should really be replaced with reading from standard input, which indeed should be supplied (unless this is actually an I/O issue).

Comment: @Dukeling Why? It's perfectly valid to start the program reading a certain file and then asking for terminal input. I don't see this as a  bad design.

Comment: @Guido It's not that it's a problem with the design, it would just be better to not depend on a file when posted on [so]. For one thing, you won't be able to use online compilers I know of. Another thing is that either you have to download the file, which shouldn't have to be done, and depends on an external site or you have to make the file yourself, which is less than ideal.

Comment: my guess: a.txt has size 1 (instead of two or thre with C/R at end

Comment: Give example of p and q values, also example of text file. Also not checking in root() if you're not outside id range is very very bad. An you say i = 134761, but you do not mention WHERE in the program it has this value.

Comment: @Dukeling, point taken!

Comment: If it is of any help, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 from a bootable ISB stick with GCC as the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The last fscanf is failing and you can't tell. Look at this output from gdb

a.txt is

```
5
```

(only that)

When we run gdb we get the segfault, we ask *where* it happened and it prints the call stack

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/guido/a.out 
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400911 in root (i=4195888) at a.c:53
53      while(i!=(*(id+i)))
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000000400911 in root (i=4195888) at a.c:53
#1  0x0000000000400889 in connected (p=0, q=4195888) at a.c:41
#2  0x00000000004007cd in main () at a.c:23
(gdb)
```

main.c:23 is

```
22         fscanf(file,"%d %d",&p,&q);
23         if(!connected(p,q))
24             unn(p,q);
```

We see that after that fscanf `p` is 0 and `q` is `4195888` (it differs from your run, this happens with undefined behaviour ;). This is caused because there were no numbers for scanf to read. Your `while (!feof(file))` won't work because, even though we haven't reached the end of file, there are no more numbers (I think we could "fix" this by scanning "%d %d\n" in the loop and "%d\n" in the start).

A more correct way would be

```
22         if(2 == fscanf(file,"%d %d",&p,&q))
23             if(!connected(p,q))
24                 unn(p,q);
```

`2` refers to the 2 format specifiers. `scanf` and friends return the number of matched elements. This way we make sure to only work on valid input. (This doesn't segfault for me, I think it fixes it fully)

What we should get out of all this is that I/O is tricky, and we should specify to read exactly what we want to read, and take care for ill-formed files.

**EDIT:** By the way, you should really declare function prototypes and specify the return types. Here is my "cleaning" of your code (http://pastebin.com/r0csiCyj). Also global variables are evil.

Comment: Even by using your version, I get Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Crap! Can you upload the a.txt file you're using?

Comment: The text file: http://d-h.st/ULK  and the C file: http://d-h.st/DgT    After implementing if(2 == fscanf(file,"%d %d",&p,&q)), I got this message on gdb:    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804872e in root (i=134761) at qunion.c:47
47  while(i!=(*(id+i)))
(gdb) where
#0  0x0804872e in root (i=134761) at qunion.c:47
#1  0x080486c6 in connected (p=10, q=11) at qunion.c:35
#2  0x08048607 in main () at qunion.c:19

Comment: It's working for me. When I run it :`1 1
1
Yes(1) or No(0)    1
1 11
0
Yes(1) or No(0)    0`. Also with 10 and 11 it works.

Comment: Could it be because of the usb stick?

Answer (score 0):

ALWAYS check the result of fopen();

Comment: Well, it did work in the quick find implementation, with only the functions changed. So I suppose this should work, right?

Answer (score 0):

In your root function you have:

```
i=*(id+i);
```

which does not check if the id+i increment is within the valid rangem since you just used a while to iterate over the data structure. The problem is that, at some point, you are going out of your allocated memory.

Some comments:

- please add the explicit returning types of each function :)
- when asking about a problem that the compiler said line XX, please indicate the line, I had to count :)

Cheers

Comment: How do I remedy the problem of allocated memory?